# TIdHttp POST returns only XML where json is expected

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-2007, indy10

In my Delphi 2007 code I'm posting to a secure web service in order to get an authentication token. Everything works well with Postman or requests made in .net languages.
But i need to access this WS using Delphi 2007... then i made this code:

```
var
  IdHTTP1 : TIdHTTP;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  jsonSend : TStringStream;
  SourceString, RetString : String;

begin
  SourceString := '{"MyJsonStuff": "blabla"'}';
  try
    IdHTTP1:=TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    //IdHTTP1.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';
    //IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
    IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    try
      LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
      LHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
      try
        IdHTTP1.IOHandler:=LHandler;
        jsonSend := TStringStream.Create(SourceString);
        RetString := IdHTTP1.Post('myUrl', jsonSend));
        jsonSend.free;
      except

      end;
        LHandler.Free;
    finally
      IdHTTP1.Free;
    end;
  except 
  end;
end;
```

This code works very well, but RetString (the WS response) is in XML format, not in jSon as expected.
I hope someone can help me with this, i don't really want to parse XML...
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Remy Lebeau suggestions I've explored the request made by Delphi and found that in the Headers there was a key that specifies XML as accepted response...

I have simply overwritten this key adding this line of code:

```
IdHTTP1.Request.Accept := '*/*';
```

And now my webservice responds as expected.

Answer (score 3):

That entirely depends on the URL you are posting to.  Just because you send a request in JSON does not necessarily mean you are going to get a reply in JSON, unless the webservice is coded to always return JSON, or if the webservice allows you to specify the desired reply format with a query string parameter in the URL itself, or in the request's `Accept` header, or a parameter in the post data.

It is also possible that the webservice may be UserAgent-sensitive, sending a different content/format to different types of clients. Many UserAgent-sensitive sites do not recognize/accept the default `TIdHTTP.Request.UserAgent` value, so you might  need to change it to mimic other clients, like Internet Explorer, Firefox, or Safari.

Use a packet sniffer like Wireshark, or an HTTP proxy/debugger like Fiddler, to analyze the HTTP requests being sent by Postman and DotNet, and then replicate those requests with `TIdHTTP` as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I've already forced my WS to respond only using JSON... but this seems a little ugly. I'll give a try to your suggestions.